# How to find not repeating values in different columns python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns that I need to compare to third and to get data that is not same in first two columns.

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import nan

df = pd.DataFrame ({'Want_value': ['a', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'v', 'b', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], 'Unwanted_value': ['r', 't', 't', 'z', 't', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], 'new_all_data': ['r', 'z', 'a', 'c', 't', 'v', 'b', 'j', 'r', 't', 'v', 'a', 'k'], 'new_values': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]})
```

Looks like this...

[image]

Basically needs to be like this, `'Want_value'` +  `'Unwanted_value'` and compare to column with name `'new_all_data'`, at the end I need values that are in `'new_all_data'` but there are not in `'Want_value'` and `'Unwanted_value'`. I hope this is clear.

The values in this minimal reproducible example that are in `'new_all_data'` and not in `'Want_value'` and `'Unwanted_value'` are `j` and `k`. These values needs to be in a new column that I put here as empty `'new_values'`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide what you expect as output in the `new_values` column?  That would go a long way to help us understand what you would like ot see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use set operations:

- `current_values = set(df.Want_value) | set(df.Unwanted_value)`: union of the unique values of `Want_value` and `Unwanted_value` columns.
- `new_values = set(df.new_all_data) - current_values`: symmetric difference, i.e. get the values that are `new_all_data` but are not in `current values`.

Then you can use `DataFrame.where` to create the `new_values` column, by getting only the values of `new_all_data` column which are in `new_values` set.

```
new_values = set(df.new_all_data) - (set(df.Want_value) | set(df.Unwanted_value))

df['new_values'] = df['new_all_data'].where(df['new_all_data'].isin(new_values))
```

Output:

```
>>> new_values

{'j', 'k'}

>>> df

   Want_value Unwanted_value new_all_data new_values
0           a              r            r        NaN
1           c              t            z        NaN
2           c              t            a        NaN
3           c              z            c        NaN
4           v              t            t        NaN
5           b            NaN            v        NaN
6         NaN            NaN            b        NaN
7         NaN            NaN            j          j
8         NaN            NaN            r        NaN
9         NaN            NaN            t        NaN
10        NaN            NaN            v        NaN
11        NaN            NaN            a        NaN
12        NaN            NaN            k          k
```